# 2023 update for: iMessages from MacBook send as my email instead of phone number

Tags: iphone, mac

Messages from MacBook sent as my email instead of phone number. Can we update this for 2023?
I am unable to fix it following 2015 instructions.
There is no send and receive using my phone option on my MAC after I signed in with an Apple ID. It defaults to my email.
I use Iphone SE.

Comment: It is possible to use iMessage on the phone without signing into your Apple ID. If you do this, then the Mac will not recognize you have a phone number (since the phone isn't signed in) and only provide email addresses.

Check that your phone Messages Send & Receive shows both phone numbers and email addresses as options and is fully signed in within the Messages part of settings.

Comment: @Ezekiel It was only showing my phone #. The problem is fixed now. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Nothing has changed since 2015, it's still in Messages prefs > iMessage, in the drop menu at he bottom…

[image]

Check the equivalent is set on your phone -

[image]

Comment: there is no option for my phone #. Start new conversation from: defaults to my email only.

Comment: Check the equivalent section on your phone… added to answer

Comment: Iphone does show my phone #. Mac only shows an emal.

Comment: I've spent a lot of time trying to fix it, reading "Apple help" etc., nothing is working.

Comment: Does the phone also show the appleID? - me.com or icloud.com depending on how long you've had the ID. Is the Mac signed into the same ID as the phone?

Comment: Does the phone also show the appleID? No. Is the Mac signed into the same ID as the phone? Yes

Comment: I'm really not sure how the phone can not be showing the apple ID; that's what the entire structure hangs on.